# To what extent is a dynamical system determined by its critical regions and the behaviours therein?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems

Suppose two dynamical systems defined on a same manifold have similar critical regions and similar behaviour in these regions, say, related by some smooth transformation, what can we say about these two dynamical systems? Are they homeomorphic? I wasn't able to find any theorem by googling.

Comment: Small test : if it were plausible, then all translation flows on the torus would be homeomorphic. This is obviously not the case (some have close orbits, others dense orbits).

Comment: What do you mean by "critical regions"?

Comment: @Evgeny I wasn't thinking clearly when I asked the question, I think I mean critical points, but maybe also other attractors.